# Embedded WebBrowser in Windows Form C# project

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a form with an embedded web browser control on it.  I am currently using `WebBrowser` and use it like so:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.Write(string.Empty);
String htmlContent = GetHTML();
doc.Write(htmlContent);
```

This writes the HTML correctly to the web browser control BUT it never clears the existing data and it just appends, so I end up with N web pages stacked on top of each other.

Is this the best control to use? If so why is it not clearing existing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true);
```

now the contents of the document will be cleared before writing.

> All calls to Write should be preceded
>   by a call to OpenNew, which will clear
>   the current document and all of its
>   variables. Your calls to [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.write%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will
>   create a new HTML document in its
>   place. To change only a specific
>   portion of the document, obtain the
>   appropriate HtmlElement and set its
>   InnerHtml property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

You should be able to call the Clear method if you need to clear contents.

Check this article for in-depth details and sample code:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/simplebrowserformfc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Call [HtmlDocument.OpenNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.opennew.aspx) between pages:

> OpenNew will clear the previous loaded
>   document, including any associated
>   state, such as variables. It will not
>   cause navigation events in WebBrowser
>   to be raised.